# Focus a window without bringing the window forward

Tags: gnome, window-manager

Is there a way to focus a certain window under Gnome *without bringing the window up*?

Background:

I'm creating a script to type an arbitrary sequence characters on a certain window/application. With the help of `xdotool`, it is possible. But any focus function that it provides -- or any other tools do -- brings the target window forward. That, I want to find a way around.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the focusing habit of windows in Ubuntu like this

First got to:

```
System -> Preferences -> Windows
```

Then Check "Select windows when the mouse moves over them"

[image: Gnome 2 Windows Preferences Dialogue]

Make sure "Raise selected windows after an interval" is deselected.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My system is already set up just like what you suggested. But what I want to do is focus a window without raising it _using a command-line tool_.

Comment: in that case I would use either wmctrl http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/dapper/man1/wmctrl.1.html or Sikuli http://sikuli.org/